# Toilet Water evaporated and now there is low water level even after flushing multiple times

Tags: plumbing, toilet

So my toilet has not been used for the past three months and upon returning i noticed that the water had evaporated. I tried flushing multiple times but the water level stays very very low (unlike how it used to be). I don’t understand what is wrong because the toilet was working perfectly fine when i left. I am unable to comment on and compare how strong the flush water pressure is currently than how it used to be,:((
Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Does the toilet actually flush waste down the drain? If so, what's the actual problem?

Comment: Water in the toilet or water in the reservoir is lower than normal? I presume the first as you normally wouldn't look inside the reservoir. As Freeman says, as long as it flushes adequately, you're fine. You could do a couple of half-flushes or pour a  bucket of water in the toilet to see if that restores the water-level. A normal flush may drain too fast, pulling too much water along.

Comment: The toilet does flush, @FreeMan but most of the water goes down the drain and the bowl water level remains unusually low

Comment: @Tonny water in the toilet bowl! ouhh how does half flushes help? i’m curious

Comment: @Jen By adding more water to restore the level without triggering a full drain-cycle. Usually when water-level drops too low it will gradually restore itself over time (after a lot of flushes) but you can "top it up" by adding water without a drain-cycle.

Comment: @Tonny ouhh does that mean that after a some more flushes, the issues will resolve by itself? Also, sorry for the lack of context (and for tmi) but i did end up having a clogged toilet because of this issue. After coming back home, i flushed the toilet and cleaned it before using but unfortunately, it did lead to a clog so i had been using the full flush button. i’m trying to resolve multiple issues simultaneously and the low bowl water level persists despite the clog.

Answer (score 2):

Look in the tank and inspect for a little tube going into a bigger tube. That big tube is the overflow and the little tube puts water back into the bowl when you flush and the tank is being refilled.
If the little tube has come out of the big tube, the water in the bowl will be lower than usually seen. It may have come out because it dried from not being used or come off the little nipple at the fill valve.

Comment: oh i can try doing that, thank you!! :))))